# JavaScript Inheritance Using .call()

Tags: javascript, inheritance, dhtmlx

I need a way to call many DHTMLX attach*() functions with certain defaults already set.  This is just one example.  If I can figure this one example out then I can apply it to all others.

DHTMLX has many functions similar to this: dhtmlXCellObject.prototype.attachToolbar(), attachTabbar(), attachRibbon(), etc... But for every single toolbar in my app there are certain settings I want to automatically apply like iconSize and iconPath.

```
dhtmlXCellObject.prototype.attachTheBetterToolbar = function (conf) {
    // https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxlayout_attachtoolbar.html
    // dhtmlXToolbarObject.prototype.attachToolbar.call(this, conf); This throws: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

    this.attachToolbar.call(this, conf);

    // I want these two settings below on every single toolbar in our app but
    // I only want to have to set them once in here.  Then throughout my
    // entire application, we will only use attachTheBetterToolbar...
    // layout.cells('a').attachTheBetterToolbar()
    // window.attachTheBetterToolbar()
    // accordian.attachTheBetterToolbar()
    // tabbar.tabs('a').attachTheBetterToolbar()
    // etc...

    this.setIconSize(18);
    this.setIconsPath(c3.iconPath);
};
```

The above code doesn't work (errors with: this.setIconSize is not a function) but I think you'll get the idea of what I'm trying to attempt. I'm reading all sorts of articles on JavaScript extend, apply, call, inheritance, etc... I feel like I'm close but something just isn't clicking.

I thought the ".call()" part would cause inheritance to happen like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16058530/3112803 (the Variation 1 - Mixin -> Inheritance example)

Comment: What does your instantiation look like?

Comment: `var t = dhtmlXLayout.cells('a').attachTheBetterToolbar();`

Comment: Not sure why you need to use `.call()`. `this.attachToolbar(conf)` should do the same thing.

Comment: You only need to use `.call()` if you want `this` in the called method to be different from the object whose method you're using.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, been on a coding bender, crosseyed.  Add it as an answer if you want credit.  Editing OP now to show what I just tried which works.

Comment: It's not an answer. The two should be equivalent, so it won't fix any problems.

Comment: If you have a solution, you should post it as an answer, not put it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I need...

```
dhtmlXCellObject.prototype.attachTheBetterToolbar = function (conf) {
    var tb = this.attachToolbar(conf);

    // this.setIconset("awesome");
    tb.setIconSize(18);
    tb.setIconsPath(c3.iconPath);

    return tb;
};
```